# How to clean-up old unused Kubernetes images/tags?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, google-kubernetes-engine

To simplify **deployment** and short term roll-back, it's useful to use a new Docker image tag for each new version to deploy on **Kubernetes**. Without clean-up this means that old images:tags are kept forever.

How can I **list all image:tag that are used by a Kubernetes container** so that I can find all old image:tag that are old and not used to delete them automatically from the **Docker Registry**?

My goal is ideally for *Google Container Engine* (GKE) to delete unused images a *Google Container Registry*.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ahmetb/7ce6d741bd5baa194a3fac6b1fec8bb7    Script to clean up Google Container Registry images pushed before a particular date

Answer (score 18):

As an alternative approach, you might consider just letting Kubernetes handle reclamation of old images for you.

Presently, the ImageManager handles reclamation of candidate images. See: [Garbage Collection](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/garbage-collection/)

> Garbage collection is a helpful function of kubelet that will clean up
>   unreferenced images and unused containers. kubelet will perform
>   garbage collection for containers every minute and garbage collection
>   for images every five minutes.

Configuration is controlled via these two [kublet cli parameters](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/):

```
  --image-gc-high-threshold=90: The percent of disk usage after which image garbage collection is always run. Default: 90%
  --image-gc-low-threshold=80: The percent of disk usage before which image garbage collection is never run. Lowest disk usage to garbage collect to. Default: 80%
```

The high/low thresholds could be tuned to force collection at an interval that works for you.

Comment: Isn't that only for local images on the cluster Nodes and not for images in the Docker Registry?

Comment: Sorry I missed to specify it in my question properly. Updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

With recent versions of kubelet use the below options as *--image-gc-high-threshold* and *--image-gc-low-threshold* are being deprecated:

```
--eviction-hard
--eviction-soft
```

More details avaialble here:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of all images used by a Kubernetes cluster, one can run the shell script:

```
for image in $(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --output=jsonpath='{..image}')
do
    echo $image
done
```

It seems however that there is no way to simply currently delete images from a Google Container Registry (see [How to remove a pushed image in Google Container Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523945))

Comment: If you need to know which images are still referenced by your cluster, and assuming you use Deployments rather than create Pods directly, you could look at ReplicaSets instead of Pods by replacing the "pods" with "rs" in your command.

Comment: The above in a sorted list with occurrence-count (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/): kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{..image}' | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' | sort | uniq -c

Answer (score 2):

You could use [docker-cleanup](https://hub.docker.com/r/meltwater/docker-cleanup/) containers running in a DaemonSet. That would cleanup any unused images on each node in your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a documented approach to do that kind of maintenance. However Openshift Origin does attempt to tackle by pruning docker images and interacting with registry to remove older blobs

We have implemented it in context to origin. The [source code](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/388478c40e751c4295dcb9a44dd69e5ac65d0e3b/pkg/cmd/admin/prune/images.go) for that it on github